# UIKit drawing is thread safe: how do you get a graphics context?

Tags: ios, uikit

So, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4557587/244340) and in [the iOS 4.0 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009559-SW29), UIKit now has some thread-safe drawing facilities:

> Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe. Specifically:
>
> - The routines used to access and manipulate the graphics context can now correctly handle contexts residing on different threads.
> - String and image drawing is now thread-safe.
> - Using color and font objects in multiple threads is now safe to do.

That's great, but how do you use it?

As far as I'm aware, any time you're not inside `-drawRect:` you can only draw using the UIKit/UIGraphics stuff if you've created your own context through `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext()` or `UIGraphicsPushContext()`, but those functions are not thread safe according to the docs, and `-drawRect()` is always called on the main thread.

I assume that creating an image context on the main thread and then starting the background method would be a really bad idea, due to race conditions aplenty.

So, how do I use this multithreaded UIKit-based drawing stuff that was introduced in iOS 4? What other ways of getting an active UIKit graphics context have I missed?

P.S. I know that I could just draw using Core Graphics and be done with it. For various reasons (legacy code) I'd like to continue using the UIKit based drawing methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My belief, based on some experience trying it and based on various documents, is that the docs for `UIGraphicsPushContext()` are incorrect.

I believe `UIGraphicsPushContext()` is in fact thread safe. The particular indication that this is true is [QA1637](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1637/_index.html), which says "Beginning with iOS 4.0, drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is thread-safe. This includes **accessing and manipulating the current graphics stack**, drawing images and strings, and usage of color and font objects from secondary threads." (emphasis mine)

I acknowledge that it is always a dicey proposition to assume thread safety in contradiction to the docs. But I believe this is a documentation error. I have opened [rdar://11161530](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1639402) to track it. Please dupe.

Comment: I've actually just opened a DTS issue about this, so I'll hopefully find out from there. The thing I didn't mention in the question was that in my trials (although I was using ...beginImageContext), most of the time things were working fine, but sometimes I was getting a crash in `NSString drawInRect:withFont:`. It's annoyingly not easily reproducible, but whenever it crashes it's there. I'm trying to work out if I'm doing something wrong or if this will just never work.

Comment: I hadn't seen that kind of crash before, but I haven't been overly aggressive in my experiments. This is quite disturbing and may suggest that my belief is incorrect. Please let us know what the DTS result is.

Comment: More info: the specific thing that crashes is `WebCore::FontFallbackList::~FontFallbackList() ()`.

Comment: Ah... remember that UIWebView is definitely, absolutely, not thread safe. I wouldn't try to do *anything* with a webview off the main thread. Some more discussion about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660999/create-a-uiimage-by-rendering-uiwebview-on-a-background-thread-iphone

Comment: No, I'm not using a web view anywhere. It's called from the NSString drawing code, call stack here: http://pastebin.com/jr4C3n3b

Comment: Interesting; they seem to be calling out to WebStringDrawing, which then calls into WebKit, which generally is not thread safe. This could be considered bug given their statement that UIKit drawing is thread safe. I'd make sure your stack trace is in the DTS; I'm very interested in what they say.

Comment: I'm definitely starting to think it's a bug in the frameworks. Not 100% yet but we believe the crash only happens when font substitution is required: some of our text had hairline space characters which aren't found in the font we wanted to use. Removing the offending characters seems to be working. I'll report this to DTS when they get back to me.

Comment: Did you hear back from DTS? We're having the exact same issue. Calling NSString drawInRect from a background thread is causing occasional crashes when it ends up doing the drawing via WebKit.

Comment: @ameir My analysis is that it's thread-safe in 4.x and broken in 5.x: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11589768/