# Bug in UIKit string drawing method?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In order to replicate a crash I was having in my application, I had to create a sample with a slightly exaggerated repeat rate that might not be practical, but one that demonstrates exactly what was happening in my app. When drawing an NSString on a background thread using `NSOperations`, there is sometimes a crash with the last call on the stack trace before the crash being `WebCore::FontFallbackList::~FontFallBackList().`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0001 target:self selector:@selector(timerDidFire:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)timerDidFire:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    NSBlockOperation *op = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height), YES, 0.0);
        NSString *string = @"Sd";
        [string drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation]; 
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();     
    }];
    [queue addOperation:op];
}
```

You can easily replicate this crash with the code above. Anyone have any insight as to the nature of this crash, and why it might be happening?
(the solution to this problem is setting `[queue setMaxConcurrentOperations:1];`)

Comment: What if you instantiate the font outside the block (i.e. on the main thread)?

Comment: Just tried it, still no difference.

Comment: As an alternative, if I draw this string with Core Text instead, I don't get a crash anymore. Might just end up doing that.

Comment: File a bug with Apple and see what they have to say about it?

Comment: @maq .. did you find any workaround, because I'm suffering from same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a regression in iOS 5.x: It happens on the 5.0 and 5.1 simulators and on a 5.1 device, but not on the 4.3 simulator or a 4.3.2 device.

It's also specifically the string drawing that seems to be broken — if all you do is string-drawing (avoiding the overhead of creating/destroying contexts), the crash happens nearly instantly:

```
-(void)threadFunc:(UIFont *)font {
  @autoreleasepool {
    NSString *string = @" ";
    CGRect r = {{0,0},{50,50}};
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(r.size, YES, 0);
    for(;;) {
      @autoreleasepool {
        [string drawAtPoint:r.origin withFont:font];
      }
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  }
}

-(void)startThreads
{
  UIFont * font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
  for (int i = 2; i--;)
  {
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadFunc:) toTarget:self withObject:font];
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** It is "nearly instant" only in multi-core environments (i.e. a dual-core device or the simulator, assuming a multi-core Mac). Otherwise, it takes on the order of 10-20 minutes to crash. I don't have a dual-core iOS 4.x device (the only possibility appears to be the iPad 2), but the single-core devices haven't crashed after over an hour.

I've raised a bug with Apple, and encourage you to do the same if it affects you.

Comment: Interesting..any ideas about Core Text and multithreading? The documentation seems to be outdated when it comes to drawing on background threads. I haven't had any issues drawing text with Core Text, but the documentation does say that (I think) frame setters and some other type of object must only be used on one thread at a time..

Comment: @mohabitar That generally means that each *instance* must only be used on one thread at a time — it should be safe to use different CTFramesetters on different threads. However, thread-safety is occasionally subtle (especially when you want to avoid unnecessary locking), problems are often rare and difficult to track down, and documentation is often wrong if it mentions thread-safety at all.

Answer (score 1):

An easy workaround for this is to replace NSString with NSAttributedString.

The crash test that @maq listed does not crash if modified like this:

```
-(void)threadFunc:(UIFont *)font {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *string = @" ";
        NSMutableAttributedString *test = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
        CGRect r = {{0,0},{50,50}};
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(r.size, YES, 0);
        for(;;) {
            @autoreleasepool {
                 UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:30.0f];
                [test addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, test.length)];
                [test drawAtPoint:r.origin];
            }
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: I should add one more thing: sometimes you will see a memory-related crash in the simulator when drawing attributed strings from inside a concurrent queue -- that same code runs fine on any actual device I've tested (verified with zombies enabled and profiling over time on an iPad 4). I ended up adding a simulator check to my code (concurrent / serial queue based on device/simulator).

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe UIKit is thread safe, and drawing from a background thread is very funky.
It might work, it might not.

The doc for UIGraphicsBeginContext actually explicitly states that you should only call this from the main thread. Clearly, multithreading is completely off the table.

Comment: According to [What's New in iOS 4.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html), all those functions should now be safe to use in multiple threads. CATiledLayer would be a bit difficult to use otherwise.

Comment: Ya and the exact thing I'm doing in my code above was done in a WWDC 2012 session video, so I'm sure it's supposed to be safe.

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions should be thread-safe. UIFont is not. I don't necessarily think it's a coincidence that your stack trace shows trouble in FontFallbackList, then.

Comment: @isaac: The doc I linked *specifically* says "Using color and font objects in multiple threads is now safe to do".