# Creating a smooth screencast video on iOS from UIView

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7

I've been trying to get my head around recording a screencast, in app, on iOS7. There are some fantastic apps out there, for example Explain Everything (which I'm not trying to compete with, replace or copy), but I can't see how they manage to get such smooth recording of drawing. It looks like they record to their own proprietary format and then export to a movie when requested by the user.

I've tried some libraries:

- [Glimpse](https://github.com/wess/Glimpse). Unfortunately it still uses renderInContext and is really slow
- [ScreenCaptureView](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673) and (what appears to be a derivative) [UIScreenCaptureView](http://www.binpress.com/app/ios-screen-capture-view/1038). The later uses the new drawHierachy methods, but it pimps the iPad's processor up to 96% and is far too slow to draw smoothly; it feels like you're dragging your finger through treacle.

It seems like recording UIView directly to a movie is just too inefficient to create a smooth, drawing based screencast like you see in apps like ShowMe or Explain Everything.

Is there an approach to recording smooth drawing, or what happens in a given UIView that is smooth and achievable? How do (good) screencast apps already out there manage this?

Comment: For a private API to do this, take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11105783/19679, in particular this project it links to: https://github.com/coolstar/RecordMyScreen . That's not a shippable solution, but it is a way of recording the screen in a performant manner.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this way - good to know. You're right though, I want a shippable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems obvious now, but it wasn't at the beginning. The above libraries all use the main thread so I implemented my own solution and used GCD to record on a background thread> This free'd up the interface and stopped the treacle like effect while recording.

Not 100% if it's thread safe or not ([this post seems to indicate that it's not](https://devforums.apple.com/message/900659#900659) but [this post suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956726/uikit-drawing-is-thread-safe-how-do-you-get-a-graphics-context) accessing the graphics stack is safe to access). It seems to work for me though. I used a [Zoul's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741323/how-do-i-export-uiimage-array-as-a-movie/3742212#3742212) and drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates to render the contents of a view in a background thread. It's surprisingly fast and I haven't had any problems yet.

Comment: What did you use as the recording approach in the background thread?

Comment: Can you please share a little bit more information about the way you solved this problem? how did you use GCD to record on the background thread? I'm about to lose my mind over this =\

Comment: Hey guys. I use dispatch_async to throw a method off the main thread. That method's job is to grab the screen's contents and use Zoul's solution to put that in a pixel buffer.

Comment: Is the code on Github by chance? Facing a similar situation and would love to see what you did. Thanks!

Comment: No sorry! But if you use Zoul's solution and a background thread you should be ok - the solution is still working happily in iOS9. Don't forget there's also ReplayKit if it's for a game.